# Add external file to payara micro application classpath

Tags: docker, jakarta-ee, java-metro-framework, payara-micro

I'm using payara micro to run my war application. Because one of the services I need to access requires metro ws, I need to provide a wsit client file to the application.

When I add it inside the war, it works fine, but since I need this file to be different depending on the environment I'm deploying, I need to inject the correct one as an external dependency to the server and I only know the right one at deployment stage. Meanwhile I already created all the artifacts and the docker image.

How can I add this file to the application without opening the war adding it manually and re build the war? I'm looking for a solution like the external modules for wildly.

I tried the --addLibs but it requires a jar.

Comment: How are you using this wsit client file?, if its only to know the address where the service you are consuming is placed, you can achieve this by other means

Comment: The only thing different we have in the file is the callback alias. That's what we require to fulfill the service

Comment: Are you creating the ws client using jax-ws: wsimport, or something similar?

Comment: We're using jaxws-maven-plugin in the maven execution. And the only thing different in the wsit file, is in a Policy, in the KeyStore configuration we have different alias for each deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by putting the right file inside the image during the deploy stage. This way we use always the same filename, but different files for each environment.